# Java consuming REST services

Tags: java, rest, url, ssl

I'm trying to consume a REST service using a Java client and I obtain `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out` exception.

If I'm using a web client (chrome, firefox) I'm able to retrieve the right answer.

I added in windows firewall an exception for java but this not solve my problem.
My connection is secured.

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        X509TrustManager[] xtmArray = new X509TrustManager[] { new OwnTrustManager() };
        sslContext.init(null, xtmArray, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        if (sslContext != null) {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext
                    .getSocketFactory());
        }
        HttpsURLConnection
                .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new ISAHostnameVerifier());



public class OwnTrustManager implements X509TrustManager{
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
}

public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
}

public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return null;
}
}


public class ISAHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier{
public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Business logic is:

```
URL url = null;
      try {

         url = new URL("https://16.9.1.82/xxxx/v23/rest");
         HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
         con.setRequestMethod("GET");
         con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
         con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
         con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "----");
         con.setRequestProperty("Host", "16.9.1.82");
         con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic U1BQQ19STTFASUJNLkNPTTptYXhhZG1pbg==");
         con.connect();
```

Comment: What happens if you connect to `https://16.9.1.82/scep/v1/rest` using your browser?

Comment: If I'm trying to connect using web browser It request me to accept a certificate and to enter my user + password. It answer correctly.

Comment: Please don't use this sort of trust manager and host name verifier. This ends up in production code far too often. Your connection is clearly *not* secure with such a trust manager and host name verifier.

Comment: Do Chrome and Firefox use a proxy, by any chance?